# What entities can be at war?

Tags: war

I wish to know, who as an entity can be at war with another party according to Islam?
A state, an instititution, a family or a person?
Also, what reasons and opponents are permitted to declare war or to be at war?

Comment: In absence of a Muslim authorithy any Muslim is asked to do jihad once he is aware of such a situation else it needs an authorithy such a caliph.

Comment: Please write an answer if you have more information

Comment: Once i have a full answer and the time and opertunity to write it i'll do so.

Answer (score -2):

> What entity?

Whoever that is responsible or supports the wrongdoer. Meaning if one person **wrongfully** kills another Muslim, then he is to be brought to court. If others stop this then they should should be punished, though I'm not sure of the extent of the punishment of others vs the individual murderer. Likely if one supports another's doing then they are deemed as equal. But don't quote me on that.

*Fight in the way of Allah those who fight you but do not transgress. Indeed. **Allah does not like transgressors**.*
https://quran.com/2/190

Say a person from country X comes and kills 1 person from country Y, and the country Y kills him and then kills 10 others and names it as collateral damage. That is NOT acceptable. It is a transgression.

*[Fighting in] the sacred month is for [aggression committed in] the sacred month, and for [all] violations is legal retribution. So whoever has assaulted you, then **assault him in the same way that he has assaulted you**. And fear Allah and know that Allah is with those who fear Him.*
https://quran.com/2/194

Basically the act and its punishment should be proportionate.

> What reasons to declare war?

*Allah does not forbid you from those who do not fight you because of religion and **do not expel you from your homes** - from being righteous toward them and acting justly toward them. Indeed, Allah loves those who act justly.*

So if one entity attempts to remove us from our homeland that we are to fight back.

Or as always self-defense is accepted.

https://quran.com/60:8

Having that said the first approach is to forgive or sign a peace treaty. If the enemies don't stop then the Muslims most protect themselves. Under no circumstance Muslims can enter the lands of their enemies. <-- such doing can only be instructed by God or his messengers

Comment: "Under no circumstance Muslims can enter the lands of their enemies." This stands in blatant contradiction to the actions (and fiqh) of even the rashidun, let alone the caliphs after them.

Comment: @G.Bach I don't know who you are talking about but no entity unless infallible has such authority. If one has done such, then since they have contradicted Quran their position is to be questioned. Any reason to position them above Quran?

Comment: What you're saying stands in contradiction to what Abu Bakr, Umar, Uthman, and Ali did. Contradicting them is something that needs quite a bit more than "yeah they blatantly went against the quran".

Comment: **<comments deleted>**. Comments should primarily be used to ask for more information and suggest improvements. Not discussions. Take it [chat] if you want to do so. And remember the [**Be Nice**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#nice) policy at **all** times.